# Add tooltip to datatables row after row.add()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datatables

I should add a tooltip to [datatables](https://datatables.net/) row

```
//initialize datatable
$scope.anomaliesTable = $('#sapTable').DataTable({
    //disable responsive
    responsive: true,
    //"bLengthChange": false,
    //deferRender:    true,
    scrollY:        '60vh',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    info:   false,
    paging : false,
    //scroller:       true,
    select: true,
    columns: [
        { data: 'can_name' },
        //other columns data
        ],
        columnDefs: [ 
            {
                "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"
            }, 
            ],              
});
```

The row are added from web socket subscription with the `row.add` method

```
$scope.anomaliesTable.row.add(data).draw(false);
```

In the other table, where the data is loaded from ajax, I used

```
rowCallback: function( row, data, index ) {
    row.setAttribute('data-toggle',"tooltip");
    row.setAttribute('data-placement',"left");
    row.setAttribute('title', 'UIID: ' + data.uuid);
}
```

but it doesn't work because it adds browser tooltip and only on the older row. Do you have some advice?

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new row, you can get newly created node by using `node()` API method.

```
var row = $scope.anomaliesTable.row.add(data).draw(false).node();
```

You can use `rowCallback` to add necessary `data-` attributes or add them after adding a new row, for example:

```
$(row).attr({
   'data-toggle': 'tooltip',
   'data-placement': 'left',
   'title': 'UIID: ' + data.uuid
});
```

You can then initialize tooltip plug-in, for example:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', row).tooltip();
```